# Error in random forest regression (Output of image computation is too large (25 bands for 903440 pixels = 106.8 MiB > 80.0 MiB)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, samplepoints

I am working with the GEDI dataset and Sentinel-2 spectral indices (about 20-40 bands). My aim is to use the Random Forest Regression to generate a map containing the information on Relative Height (RH99 for example). The problem happens when I try to increase the number of bands (spectral indices) and number of pixels. As far as I'm concerned, I have to reduce the number of bands or pixels in the `ee.image.sample` or change the `tileScale` to avoid this error. However, I want to add more bands and increase more points to test and also improve the regression. How could I deal with this error without reducing pixels and the number of bands? How could I sample more points without increasing pixels? (ideally about thousands of points)

[image]

https://code.earthengine.google.com/306dbc2029e826ab408584904277982c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you got was quite accurate. Increase the `tileScale` in your `reduceRegions()` call. I set it to `16` (the max value), and your script ran.

```
var training = S2_composite.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingData,
  properties: [heightBand],
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you in advance. If I want to sample more points, are there any ways to do this?

Comment: It's tricky, since the data is so sparse. You can look at my script for doing these regressions. Tweak the `numPixels` in `toReferenceData()`. https://code.earthengine.google.com/10305addfe760def14763ac7d85fcb8a

Comment: That's great work. I have one more question about your work: How could you split the reference data to training data and validation data?

Comment: You can do it exactly as you did: https://code.earthengine.google.com/34a1dba087e929a944443f74d8e67512

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It helps me a lot.

Comment: One more problem is that In my work, the training and validation data contained both the rh feature and random column but for your work, it has no more rh feature. Could you explain to me? since, with the rh feature, I'm gonna print the correlation chart between the classification and rh.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. The each feature in `validationData` contains an `rh95` property.

Comment: Sorry my bad. You're right. Since I want to print a chart using ui.Chart.feature.byFeature between 'rh' and 'classification' after doing the regression, it do not contain anymore

Comment: I changed a little bit your work to provide the chart (What I've already done in my work). But it seems not work: https://code.earthengine.google.com/777e5c95c506a097222d0babfd579321

Comment: You have to keep the geometries in `toTrainingData()`: https://code.earthengine.google.com/87228491aa6e819d14669e909df6ea0d

Comment: Yes, I got that point. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to extract all the GEDI datapoints to csv file? (including bands). I got stuck for few days. I strongly need a specific help